# Segmentation fault in C when process large scale files

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc

I wrote a program to work with large scale files (as graph). I used a linked list for this purpose. When I run it on a small file everything is good and the result is correct. When I run it on large file it has a problem that you can see in the following picture:

[image: Segmentation fault error]

And before the error, `temp` variable is ok and at each iteration, it has the correct value. But, when the error happens it is `0x0`!

[image: My code]

What is the main reason for this problem?

The struct that I use it is:

```
struct path {
 int node;
 struct path *next;
};

/* Head and Tail for Paths List */
struct path *pathHead = NULL;
struct path *pathTail = NULL;

/* Path List structure */
struct path_list {
  struct path *path_head;
  struct path *path_tail;
  struct path_list *next;
};

/* Head and Tail for Path List Linked Lists */
struct path_list *path_list_head = NULL;
struct path_list *path_list_tail = NULL;
```

Comment: please post your code here and not as an image

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TobySpeight Ok. But I do not familiar with some of them that you mentioned. I am using NetBeans. The problem is out of memory access. When I use `malloc` after a long time it returns `Null`. IS there any way to share my code completely and talk about it?

Comment: If `malloc()` returns `NULL` that means it can't allocate any memory for you.  You can't use the returned null pointer for anything.  You might be able to find a configurable `malloc` to stress your code (or just `ulimit` your process's memory so that it can fail on a small example program).

Comment: @TobySpeight But when I see the `Memory` usage percent in `Task Manager` it is near 68%! And so there is capacity!

Comment: @TobySpeight What do you think about the second struct without `path_tail`? But I think everytime I must read all list to access the last node to add a new node. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This means `malloc()` failed and returned `NULL`.** This is probably happening because you're **out of memory**.

---

From [**`malloc()`'s man pages**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

> The `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. **On error, these functions return `NULL`.**

You can check `malloc()`'s return value and handle this case so that your program doesn't segfault:

```
if ((temp = malloc(sizeof(struct path))) == NULL)
  {
    printf("%s", "malloc() failed!");
    // Clean exit?
  }
```

You could also use [**errno**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) for error handling.

---

Comment: Why for a small file is correct? What should I do?

Comment: 1. add error checking, so your program can give a meaningful error instead of just crashing when memory runs out, 2. try not tu use more memory than available.

Comment: And if you can, try to have a ligth struct for your linked list (I don't know how you have declared your structure)

Comment: Yes, it has `out of memory` error and temp is NULL. Is there any way to share my code and talk about it?

Comment: I checked it and it returns `12 errno`.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for why a call to `malloc` returns `NULL`?

Well, not enough memory.

But you know, you can keep yourself out of this kind of pain by checking the return value of your `malloc` call and if it fails, print why it has failed.

Use `errno` (and `strerror`).